# input placeholder iphone

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

Проблема в input с placeholder не центруется на технике Apple.

```
  input{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: normal !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #292929;
    border: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    &::placeholder{
      color: #AAAAAA;
      line-height: normal !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Я знаю что тут писали об этом, но я уже все пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной ситуации была проблема в шрифте. Bebasus
После замены шрифта и `line-height: 100%;` все стало на свои места

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через флекс

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```